# React.js Deleting Specific Element

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm very new to react.js but am learning a ton. I have a specific problem I am trying to solve. I want to be able to check a checkbox to remove a dynamically created element.

Currently my code is set up to render a number of elements, and that number (in element state) is added by 1 every time a button is clicked.

Obviously I could just subtract the state num by 1, however am trying to delete a specific element.

How would I try and remove a specific element by it's id?

Current Code:

```
  4 class FieldSection extends Component{
  5   constructor(){
  6     super()
  7
  8     this.state ={
  9       numberOfFields: 1
 10     }
 11   }
 12   addField = () => {
 13       const { numberOfFields } = this.state;
 14       this.setState({ numberOfFields: numberOfFields + 1 });
 15     }
 16
 17   listFields = (numberOfFields) => {
 18     var fields = [];
 19     for(var i=0; i<numberOfFields; i++){
 20       fields.push(
 21         (<Field />)
 22       )
 23       setId();
 24     }
 25     return fields;
 26   }
 27
 28   render () {
 29     const {listFields, addField} = this;
 30     const {numberOfFields} = this.state;
 31     return (
 32       <div>
 33           <label><u>Fields</u></label>
 34           {listFields(numberOfFields)}
 35           <div id="fieldButtons">
 36             <button id="addField" type="button" onClick={addField}> Add Field </butt    on>
 37             <button id="removeField" type="button"> Remove Field </button>
 38           </div>
 39       </div>
 40     )
 41   }
 42 }
```

Comment: What does `setId()` do and what should "Remove Field" button do?

Comment: setId() is what sets the id by how many of that element exists. Remove Field does not do anything yet, but that is the button that is clicked and will show the remove check-boxes

Answer (score 0):

Check this: the point to start implementing what you want to do in more correct way:

```
    class FieldSection extends Component{
      constructor(){
        super()
        this.state ={
         allFields: []
        }
      }
      addField = () => {
        this.setState({ allFields: getFieldId()});
      }

      removeField = (id) => {
          //get new array if fields without element you want to delete
          const editedArray = this.state.allFields.filter(num =>  num !== id)
          this.setState({allFields: editedArray})
      }

      render () {
         var fields = [];
         for(var i=0; i<this.state.allFields; i++){
            fields.push(<Field key={allFields[i]} id={allFields[i]} 
                          deleteAction = (id)=> this.removeField(id)/>)
         }
         return (
           <div>
             <label><u>Fields</u></label>
             {fields}
             <div id="fieldButtons">
               <button id="addField" type="button" onClick={addField}>Add Field </button>
               <button id="removeField" type="button"> Remove Field </button>
             </div>
           </div>
          )
      }
    }
    //********Field Component************//

    class FieldSection extends Component{
      render() {
         return (
             <div>
                <div id={this.props.id}>My field</div>
                <div onClick={()=> this.props.deleteAcion(this.props.id}>Delete field</div>
             </div>
         )
      }
    }
```